# Vectorize Environment Access in R

Tags: r, hash, vectorization, environment

So I have created an environment (which I am trying to use as a hashtable).

To clarify I'm accessing the values stored in the environment with this:

```
    hash[["uniqueIDString"]] ## hash takes a uniqueID and returns a 
                             ## dataframe subset that is precomputed
```

I also have a function called func which returns some subset of the rows returned by hash. It works fine for single calls but it isn't vectorized so I can't use it in a transform which is kind of vital.

The following doesn't work:

```
    df <- transform(df,FOO = func(hash[[ID]])$FOO)
```

It gives me an error about having the wrong number of arguments for the hash which I presume is because it's passing a vector of IDs to my environment and the environment doesn't know what to do.

**EDIT**: The exact error is:

```
    Error in hash[[ID]] : 
      wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

**EDIT**: With Rob's suggestion I receive the following error:

```
    Error in hash[ID] : 
      object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

**EDIT**: For clarification I'm attempting to use the hash lookup in the context of a transform where the values in the ID column are looked up in the hashtable and passed to func so that the output can become a new column.

Comment: You are using the single-index `[[` operator on a non-length-1 vector `df$ID`.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski Made that change and the error now states that object of type 'environment' is not subsettable. Ideas?

Comment: I think the more-general, still-bizarre behavior is: "f = function(x) { hash[[x]] }; apply(vector, 2, f)" produces "Error in hash[[x]] : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment", even though hash[[x]] returns what you want when not inside an apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use environments as hash tables a lot, the way to retrieve values corresponding to multiple keys is to use`mget`:

```
hash <- new.env()
hash[['one']] <- 'this is one'
hash[['two']] <- 'this is two'
mget(c('one', 'two'), envir = hash)
```

which returns a list

```
$one
[1] "this is one"

$two
[1] "this is two"
```

If you need the output as a vector, use `unlist`:

```
unlist(mget(c('one', 'two'), envir = hash))
```

gives you

```
          one           two 
"this is one" "this is two"
```

**UPDATE** If your IDs come from a data frame, you'd need to use `unlist` to convert that column to vector:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('one', 'two'))
unlist(mget(unlist(df$id), envir = hash))
```

Comment: Replace `hash[[ID]]` with `mget(ID, envir = hash)`?

Comment: (deleted previous comment because I misunderstood your answer) This is similar to what I want to do but when I try to call mget with a column field name it gives me an invalid argument error.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski Yes, and use `unlist` if the `func` that is mentioned in the question has to have a vector.

Comment: @ThomasoftheScotts Can you provide a small subset of your data so that we ca reproduce what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AlexVorobiev Is it possible to get the values from a column in the dataframe and use them as that vector as the first argument to mget?

Comment: @AlexVorobiev Unfortunately no, it's a proprietary dataset.

Comment: @AlexVorobiev That throws an error in mget for an invalid first argument which is really odd because I checked just unlist(df$id) and it put up a single correct ID for each but when I try to pass the vector of IDs to mget it complains that it's an invalid first argument.

Comment: GAH! I'm an idiot, I checked the class of the column and I guess when I read in the data.frame it interpreted my ID string as a numeric. Thanks so much Alex and Rob!